# nested python dictionary is not adding the new value , but updating it

Tags: python, dictionary

I am reading a csv file and saved it in variable *csvReader*
*type(csvReader)* gives: **<class 'csv.DictReader'>**

Code to create dictionary :

```
temp=0
for rows in csvReader:
            #to get the coin_name
            val=rows['Pair']   
            l=val.index('-')+1
            r=val.index('_')
            coin_name = val[l:r]

            #add new value to data dictionary
            data[coin_name]={temp:rows}
            temp+=1
```

Here value of each **rows** is a dictionary like this :

```
{'Market': 'ETHINR', 'Pair': 'I-ETH_INR', 'Total Quantity': '0.0071', 'Remaining Quantity': '0.0', 'Price Per Unit': '208811.99', 'Avg Price': '208811.99', 'Fee 
Amount': '1.482565129', 'Side': 'buy', 'Order Type': 'limit_order', 'Status': 'filled', 'Exchnage code': 'I', 'Created At': '2021-06-04 22:13:39 UTC', 'Updated At': '2021-06-04 22:21:05 UTC'}
```

**Python dictionary** i **want** to create :

```
data={
      "BTC":{
          1 : {"date" : "...", price : "..."},
          2 : {"date" : "...", price : "..."},
          3 : {"date" : "...", price : "..."}
        },
      "ETH":{
          4 : {"date" : "...", price : "..."},
          5 : {"date" : "...", price : "..."}
        }
     }
```

the dictionary i am **getting** :

```
data={
      "btc":{
          3 : {"date" : "...", price : "..."}
        },
      "eth":{
          5 : {"date" : "...", price : "..."}
        }
     }
```

I tried:

```
data[coin_name][temp]={temp:rows}
```

but it shows error that, **KeyError: 'BTC'**. I thaught maybe it do not have data[coin_name] in the first place thats why this happens. So when i ran a for loop to add the 'BTC' and then add the above loop to add rows to it 'BTC': { 1: rows} , the new problem is this is not added to the data.
I am using this on flask, so maybe this is reloading again , i don't know!
How can i get my desired dictionary here?

Comment: You need `data[coin_name]` to be assigned an empty dict if it has not been assigned yet. So an if statement after `if coin_name not in data` with a `data[coin_name] = {}` will help

Comment: Thanks @Andrew , it did the trick